# Which model is suitable for predicting percentages?

Tags: r, regression, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I came across this problem to predict loss on a loan-default, based on various input attributes. You not only have to predict loss/no-loss but also predict what percentage of loan will be lost (0-100%). I am wondering how does one go about modeling such a scenario:

1. Should loss/no-loss(0%) be modeled as a categorical classification (using SVM etc), since no-loss is quite common?
2. If you use Linear Regression, how do you keep the loss within the bounds of 1-100?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd just post this on kaggle forum given the rule about keeping all information within team or public on the forum... but if not then this is better suited for crossvalidated than stackoverflow. Also, I think you're going to want to ask about what to do with overdispersion.

Comment: Agree with David, there is no programming question here. Would recommend asking on http://crossvalidated.com instead.

Comment: Thanks david. I am just a curious onlooker and wasn't sure if asking here violates competition rules any more than asking your stat buddy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generalised linear model with a logit link and binomial family.

Here is a [link](http://data.princeton.edu/R/glms.html) to get you started.